# Filtering Todos with seletion tag and checkbox

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to build a simple 3page Todo app using React ,React-router and Context API.
I want to filter out my Todo based on completed, Uncompleted and All using a checkbox and selection tag in the Task page. I've tried many options but all to no avail.

These are the codes for the select tag and checkbox

```js
<select>
  <option value="all">all</option>
  <option value="completed">completed</option>
  <option value="uncompleted">uncompleted</option>
</select>

<ul id={darkTheme ? 'dark-theme' : 'light-theme'}>
  {items.map((items, id) => (
    <div key={id} className="list">
      <input className="checkbox" type="checkbox" />
      <li>{items}</li>
      <input
        onClick={() => deletehandler(id)}
        type="button"
        value="delete"
      />
    </div>
  ))}
</ul>
```

For my function that adds the todos to the list

```js
const onAdd = (inputText) => {
  setItems((prevItems) => {
    return [...prevItems, inputText];
  });
};
```

I tried using `useState` with a value of false and the assigned it the checkbox for me to toggle between true and false. But unfortunately all checkboxes are toggling at the same time, meaning I if i change the state of a particular checkbox to true. The next checkbox automatically changes to true.

```js
const [completed, setCompleted] = useState(false);

// The function handling the complete state

const CompleteHandler = () => {
  setCompleted(!completed);
};
```

Answer (score 1):

There's so much in here you may have to add & update.

- have a `default` condition to display your `current` `todos`
- have a condition statements to update your `todos` according to your `query` (`select` `options`)
- structure your `data` or `todos` so that you can track their **completion status** (for this example: `todos: [{ id: '1a', task: 'Task A', status: 0 }]`. Where `status=0` for **uncomplete** task whereas `status=1` for **completed** task)
- your `checkbox` should be conditional depending on the `status`. If `status=1`, it **should be checked**. Otherwise, no.
- Most alteration of your `data` or `todos` should be done in `Context API`

#### `Demo.js`

- using `switch` statements in `useEffect` with **dependencies** of `query` & `todos` to display **current & updated** `filteredTodos` (by `default`, `filteredTodos` will contain **current** `todos`)
- calling `function` of `addTodo()` to handle adding of new todo

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import { useTodo } from '../contexts/TodoState'
import { addTodo } from '../contexts/TodoAction'
import TodoList from './TodoList'

const Demo = () => {
  /** context state  */
  const [todoState, todoDispatch] = useTodo()
  const { todos } = todoState
  
  const [query, setQuery] = useState('')
  const [filteredTodos, setFilteredTodos] = useState([])
  const [todo, setTodo] = useState('')

  /** filter items according to query */
  useEffect(() => {
    (() => {
      switch (query) {
        case 'completed':
          setFilteredTodos(todos.filter(todo => todo.status === 1))
          break 
        case 'uncomplete':
          setFilteredTodos(todos.filter(todo => todo.status === 0))
          break
        default:
          setFilteredTodos(todos)
          break;
      }
    })()
  }, [query, todos])

  /** todo add new - function */
  const handleAddNew = () => {
    // simple validation
    if(todo === '') {
      alert('Cannot be empty todo!')
      setTodo('')
    }

    // funciton from Context API
    addTodo(todoDispatch, {
      id: Date.now(),
      task: todo,
      status: 0
    })

    // reset state
    setTodo('')
  }

  return (
    <>
      <div>
        <input placeholder="Add new todo" value={todo} onChange={e => setTodo(e.target.value)} />
        <button style={{marginRight: 10}} onClick={() => handleAddNew()} >Add</button>
        <label>Choose a car:</label>
        <select onChange={e => setQuery(e.target.value)}>
          <option value="all">All</option>
          <option value="completed">Completed</option>
          <option value="uncomplete">Uncomplete</option>
        </select>
      </div>
      <TodoList todos={filteredTodos} />
    </>
  )
}

export default Demo
```

#### `TodoList.js`

- display list of `filteredTodos`
- handle **updating** `todo` `status` & **deleting** `todo`
- at **line 50** (see in sandBox link below) is where we control which **checkbox is checked** and which is don't

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import { useTodo } from '../contexts/TodoState'
import { deleteTodo, updateStatusTodo } from '../contexts/TodoAction'

const TodoList = ({ todos }) => {
  const [todoState, todoDispatch] = useTodo()

  /** todo global - state */
  const [todoId, setTodoId] = useState('')

  /** todo update status - states */
  const [intention, setIntention] = useState('')
  const [status, setStatus] = useState(false)

  /** todo delete - state */
  const [isDelete, setIsDelete] = useState(false)
  
  /** todo update status - function */
  useEffect(() => {
    (() => {
      if(status) {
        updateStatusTodo(todoDispatch, todoId, intention)

        // reset all state
        setTodoId('')
        setIntention('')
        setStatus(false)
      }
    })()
  }, [status])

  /** todo delere - function */
  useEffect(() => {
    (() => {
      if(isDelete) {
        deleteTodo(todoDispatch, todoId)

        // reset states
        setTodoId('')
        setIsDelete(false)
      }
    })()
  }, [isDelete]) 

  return (
    <ul>
      {todos?.length > 0 && todos.map(todo => (
        <li key={todo.id}>
          <input
            checked={todo.status === 1 ? true : false} 
            type="checkbox" 
            value={todoId} 
            onChange={() => {
              setTodoId(todo.id)
              setIntention(() => todo.status === 0 ? 'completed' : 'uncomplete')
              setStatus(true)
            }} 
          />
          <label>{todo.task} ({todo.id} - {todo.status})</label>
          <button style={{marginLeft: 10}} 
            onClick={() => {
              setTodoId(todo.id)
              setIsDelete(true)
            }}
          >
            X
          </button>
        </li>
      ))}
    </ul>
  )
}

export default TodoList
```

#### `TodoReducer.js` (Context API)

- this is where all logic affecting/updating our `todos` happen

```js
export default (state, action) => {
  switch(action.type) {
    case 'ADD_TODO':
      return {
        ...state,
        todos: [action.payload, ...state.todos]
      }
    case 'DELETE_TODO':
      return {
        ...state,
        todos: state.todos.filter(todo => todo.id !== action.payload)
      }
    case 'UPDATESTATUS_TODO':
      return {
        ...state,
        todos: state.todos.map(todo => {
          if(todo.id === action.payload.id) todo.status = action.payload.intention
          return todo
        })
      }
    default:
      return state
  }
}
```

You can refer this [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/reacttodosimple-5fkjg?file=/src/App.js) for reference.

Comment: Thank you so much. I'll try it out